# Relate Mysql tables based on user session

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

i need your help doing a script to get user data from two table for user logged in.

This is my configuration:

- I used [THIS GUIDE](http://it.wikihow.com/Creare-uno-Script-Sicuro-per-il-Login-Usando-PHP-e-MySQL) doing the login form and session
- My files are:

> ---- Login.php (This file contains the login form in html)
>   ---- db_connect.php (This is for database connection)
>   ---- process_login.php (This controls the connection data and redirect user after login)
>   ---- function.php (This is for `sec_session_start ();` and function to retrieve data from database)

Database tables:

1. members
2. addusr

OK, the problem is this:

I've 2 table in my database (called: test), the **first table** hold primary user data (id, username, password, salt)

The second table hold: id, Name, Surname, biography, day (birthday day), month (birthday month), year (birthday year).

When user registers, the program print user data in database. 
When user login, i need to get user data as name and surname but How to recover this data from second table?

Until now I have developed this:

```
function get_talkm3_nome () {
    include 'db_connect.php';

    $conn = $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    $query = "SELECT addusr.nome FROM addusr, members WHERE members.username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "" . $row["nome"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Si è verificato un errore, non ho trovato nulla";
    }
```

This file is stored in function and i call it to print the name of actually logged in user, but it doesn't work properly because instead of getting the name of current logged in user (my name) i get this:  *Fabrizio, lorenzo, test3*

But how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do the tables have any field that's identical? For example, is username in both tables? If so, you can JOIN on the condition that the two tables have the same username.

Comment: They have nothing in common, probably this is the problem

Comment: That is most certainly the problem. Are you able to modify the tables so that both share the username field?

Comment: I had already thought about putting a join but just because the two tables are not related to each other, I can not use it.

Comment: Maybe you should redesign your database? You could fit all of those fields into a single table called "users" or something.

Comment: @KallumTanton I can understand wanting user information and user credentials separated, but I also understand having one table for simplicity. I would also recommend a redesign to help accomplish your goal.

Comment: a better way of linking them would be off of the primary keys, such as `id`.  From the way you have it structured, it looks like that might be your connection?

Comment: @MariM I do think simplicity is key in some scenarios and tables with such small amounts of fields would benefit from this. nomistic If leofabri wants to keep the tables separated then primary keys will be required. All tables should really be defined by a unique primary key anyway.

Comment: Ok, will be the best solution but since I will have many other tables relate to each other i have to find the solution.
This system will host a large amount of users, you say that the best solution is to put your username in all tables ?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with having more than one table, and there are good reasons for doing so, however if all of the data you have on both tables is a direct one-to-one relationship, there's not really a need to have two tables, unless you are trying to maintain a control on certain data.  In this case, you are probably better off with everything on the same table, unless there are security reasons for keeping the user information separate

Comment: don't put username on all tables.  create an id to link them.  it's a lot cleaner to index off of a primary key integer.

Comment: I agree with this entire conversation. It's good to weigh the pros and cons of one table versus two and to choose the design most appropriate for your application.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, thanks. Yes  I want to separate the table for safety reasons, i'm working on small website where user can register and chat online. I've encrypted all the data in the first table (except username and email), I could join these two tables but later I wanted to do another table containing the various chat, and to pick recent messages I have to organize a third table

Comment: Any solution? The table need to be simple and secure, but i don't know how to relate them in this case

Comment: I checked the code again, because i modified the login script. The two table have an id indicator that auto increment when i put data inside columns. But the solution can be this, i could relate the id of tables (when user register,  the information are printed inside member table and at the same time the other tables i will print the same id as the "members table" even if they are empty). What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

you need 2 tables, with a column in each table, this column must have the same value in both tables for establish a relationship between them (foreign key).
Then for the query you must need an inner join for obtain the data from the 2 tables.

Here an example from w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp
In the example the foreign key is the column CustomerID.

I recommend you this page for learn web technologies like mysql & php.

Comment: Yes, thank you Dante, I appreciate your answer. You have confirmed what a want to do. Thank you again, now I can continue my project. Happy coding!